# Is Wifi hotspot really different form repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking

Somewhere on the net says repeater is to extend the wifi signal where the signal is weak.

It also says hotspot is to create your own private network.

My real question is: Can't hotspot also extend the wifi signal where the signal is weak? I heard using a wifi repeater makes the speed of internet slower than not using it. However, I didn't find anyone saying wifi hotspot will make the speed of the internet slower.

If that's the case, I want to use wifi hotspot to extend the wifi signal to my room without slowing the speed of the internet down.

Am I understanding the difference between Hotspot and the repeater correctly?

I am talking about the hotspot mode and the repeater mode of devices such as this http://products.ncix.com/detail/d-link-dir-505-wireless-n-travel-88-72550-1020.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hotspot (access point) needs to be wired to your network. A repeater extends a Wifi signal without being physically attached to the network via ethernet. It just receives Wifi frames and retransmits them, extending the range of an access point which is connected to the physical network.

Comment: "In HotSpot Mode, there is no cord plugged into the Dir505.  
You use the setup wizzard to turn another wireless routers signal into a HotSpot that can be used by multiple devices." This is from http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=49810.0

Seems like this device does not need physical connection for making a hotspot.

Comment: Marketing information isn't good information to go by on a technical QA site. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_(Wi-Fi) gives a reasonable definition of "HotSpot" as being a wireless access network with a physical network link to the internet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater defines a repeater as exactly that. It accepts frames from wireless network, and then rebroadcasts them.

Comment: Oh so hotspot is the network area that uses access point? Does that mean the area around a repeater that is not reachable by the signal of the original access point is not called hotspot?

Comment: And in this case, now I want to reword my question. Can't an access point device extend the weak signal without slowing down the speed? http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=1605297#p1605297

In this link, it says using a repeater will decrease the bandwidth when it doesn't say so for the access point. I don't understand how access point does not decrease the bandwidth when a repeater does.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, a repeater repeat what it receives.  This mean that to transmit a frame from the station to the AP, it has to be sent twice, first from the station to the repeater, then from the repeater to the AP.

However, most repeaters repeat on the same radio channel. This mean that the repeater cannot send and receive at the same time. So when it transmit a frame to the AP, it cannot receive a frame from the station.  This essentially halves the data rate, since you need twice the time to transmit a frame and nobody can transmit anything else on the same channel at the same time.

If you add another wired AP and set it to a different non-overlapping channel, then it will not slow down the previous AP at all. You will double the total capacity of the network while extending the coverage. If the added AP uses the same channel as the previous AP, then it will extend the coverage, but because both AP share the same channel, it will not increase the total capacity of the network, but rather reduce it, because of radio issues like the hidden station effect, among other things.

Comment: So "If" a repeater can repeat on a different radio channel, the bandwidth will not be decreased?

Comment: @whiteSkar: It will not dramatically decrease. It may stay the same or decrease a bit. Now good luck finding a cheap dual-radio repeater.

Answer (score -2):

The Main difference is that in repeater mode you will be on the same Local Area network (LAN) of the primary router. That means if 4 computers are connected to the primary router than the same can also be discovered and communicated using Repeater. but if you use a WIFI HOTSPOT then it will create a seperate LAN of its own and the only communication shared between the primary router and Hotspot is the internet. Therefore you would NOT be able to access the computers and Harddrives connected to primary router in Hotspot mode except the internet shared from the primary router. Hope it helps

Comment: -1. This is in general not true. It looks you refer to daisy-chained NATs, but one can use almost any WiFi capable home router as a switch only (disable DHCP, connect the primary router to LAN port). In this case there's no additional LAN. Where I work we have a single LAN with multiple WiFi hotspots (different SSIDs) this way. Another issue: I think your last statement should be the other way around. From within the secondary LAN you can access the primary LAN and WAN; you cannot freely access the secondary LAN from the primary one (nor from WAN); it's about which way you cross the NAT.